# how do i get all values inside cdata through regular expression?

Tags: regex, html-parsing

```
[CDATA[The presence of proteins can be detected by the Biuret test.<br/>
                            (i) Crush the food sample and put some of it into a clean test tube. Add some
                            sodium hydroxide solution.<br/>
                            (ii) Cork the test tube and shake it to mix the food with the sodium hydroxide
                            solution. Then add a little copper sulphate solution. Cork and shake it
                            again.<br/>If the solution turns blue, there is no protein in the food. But it turns violet, there is protein in the food.]]
```

Comment: did you mean this `(?<=CDATA\[)[^\[\]]*`, in ns it would be `(?<=CDATA\\[)[^\\[\\]]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\[[^\[\]]*?\]
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sA8iT4/4